# Cannot read property 'icon' of undefined

Tags: ionic-framework, leaflet, font-awesome

I am having the same error as mentioned here 
[Leaflet awesome marker plugin throwing icon not defined error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56506081/leaflet-awesome-marker-plugin-throwing-icon-not-defined-error). I am new to Ionic and this is the first time that I am using leafet-awesome markers.

I have tried this solution with no success.

index.html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css"
    integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ=="
    crossorigin="" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/leaflet/leaflet.awesome-markers.css">

<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js"
    integrity="sha512-gZwIG9x3wUXg2hdXF6+rVkLF/0Vi9U8D2Ntg4Ga5I5BZpVkVxlJWbSQtXPSiUTtC0TjtGOmxa1AJPuV0CPthew=="
    crossorigin=""></script>
```

page.ts:

```
var redMarker = L.AwesomeMarkers.icon({
      icon: 'coffee',
      markerColor: 'red'
    });

    L.marker([this.lat, this.lng], {icon: redMarker}).addTo(this.map);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `leaflet.awesome-markers.js` in the html

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Leaflet.awesome-markers/2.0.0/leaflet.awesome-markers.min.js"></script>
```

**UPDATE**

I tried with the ionic Icons, but it worked also not for me. With the Font-Awesome it works.

Add the font-awesome css:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha256-46qynGAkLSFpVbEBog43gvNhfrOj+BmwXdxFgVK/Kvc=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
```

And

```
var redMarker = L.AwesomeMarkers.icon({
      icon: 'coffee',
      markerColor: 'red',
      prefix: 'fa'
    });

    L.marker([this.lat, this.lng], {icon: redMarker}).addTo(this.map);
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, unfortunately I am still getting that error.